# How to create hamburger menu in android simple way with reusable code?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, hamburger-menu

I know how to create android hamburger menu, many tutorials are available.

I want to create Hamburger menu in each class, to call one method in common class which method have hamburger menu code. Also my hamburger menu inside listview with options.

How to create like this hamburger menu. I want to reduce my code and provide reusable code to others. Please help me.

Comment: Implement Navigation Drawer in your BaseActivity, then extend that activity when you want to create a new one with Navigation Drawer http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: in this way no need to write hamburger menu code in each activity???

Comment: ...You should read something about OOP, inheritance, then start working on Android apps. And to answer your question, NO. If you implement something in a class, all classes that inherit that class will have that thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take an Activity and in that Activity's layout file put the following code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_new">


<put your layout here................>

        </FrameLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_all"

        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:theme="@style/list_item_appearance"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" >


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

After that in your Activity file:

```
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        if (drawerLayout != null) {
            drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.list_back, GravityCompat.START);

            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(HomeActivity.this, drawerLayout,
                    toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

                    invalidateOptionsMenu();

                }
            };
            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        }
 @Override

    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }


    @Override

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles

        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }
```

And then take some fragments for adding the same navigation menu in every layout and call them like:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.drawer_home:
                        txt_title.setText("Home");
                        Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        finish();
                        return true;

                    // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                    case R.id.drawer_artist:
                        txt_title.setText("Artists");
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new ArtistsFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        return true;

                   }
        });
```